# How to list all files that do not contain two different strings

Tags: shell, scripting, grep

List all the files that do not contain 2 different strings

I have a **dir** with numerous files named in a pattern e.g **file1.txt**

I can list all the files that do not contain one string

```
grep -l "String" file*
```

How can I list files that do not contain two strings I tried?

```
grep -l "string1|string2" file*
```

Comment: Do you mean to use the `-L` option (`-l` shows files whose contents *do* match the given regular expression)?

Comment: If a file contains just one of the 2 strings should that file's name be printed or not? Also, if string1 contained "f.o" and the string "flo" existed in a file, should that be considered a match or not?

Comment: Yes i am trying to list the files that do not contain either string

Comment: @EdMorton not only files that contain neither string should be returned

Comment: @Paul33 OK, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need the parameter `e` for grep, or using egrep.

With egrep:

```
egrep -L "string1|string2" file*
```

Comment: Or, just escape the "|": `grep -l "string1\|string2"`

Comment: Nice! I did not know that. I was thinking in `grep -l -e "string1|string2"`

Comment: `egrep` makes it easier to type, as it is probably more common to use `|` as the alternation operator than as literal text.

Comment: @chepner has already commented that it should be ``-L`` for listing files **not** containing pattern.

Comment: Thank you for letting me now. I update my answer to reflect it.

Comment: The above will treat each "string" as a regular expression so "f.o" will match "foo" or "flo" or... I assume the OP really wants to search for strings, not REs since he named them "string".

Comment: Thanks of the reply i tried the above egrep -L "string1|string2" file* but it is still only returning the files with string2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to just print the names of files that contain ALL strings, here's a solution that will work for any number of strings and will do a string comparison, not a regular expression comparison:

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v strings="string1 string2" '
BEGIN{ numStrings = split(strings,stringsA) }
{
   matchCnt = 0
   for (stringNr=1; stringNr<=numStrings; stringNr++)
      if ( index($0,stringsA[stringNr]) )
         matchCnt++
}
matchCnt == numStrings { print FILENAME }
' file*
```

Hang on, I just noticed you want to print the files that do NOT contain 2 strings. That would be:

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v strings="string1 string2" '
BEGIN{ numStrings = split(strings,stringsA) }
{
   matchCnt = 0
   for (stringNr=1; stringNr<=numStrings; stringNr++)
      if ( index($0,stringsA[stringNr]) )
         matchCnt++
}
matchCnt == numStrings { matchesAll[FILENAME] }
END {
   for (fileNr=1; fileNr < ARGC; fileNr++) {
      file = ARGV[fileNr]
      if (! (file in matchesAll) )
         print file
   }
}
' file*
```

To print the names of the files that contain neither string would be:

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v strings="string1 string2" '
BEGIN{ numStrings = split(strings,stringsA) }
{
   for (stringNr=1; stringNr<=numStrings; stringNr++)
      if ( index($0,stringsA[stringNr]) )
         matchesOne[FILENAME]
}
END {
   for (fileNr=1; fileNr < ARGC; fileNr++) {
      file = ARGV[fileNr]
      if (! (file in matchesOne) )
         print file
   }
}
' file*
```